# Why does my application not close gracefully when using an Appbar?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, .net-core, appbar

Playing with Appbars via https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6741/AppBar-using-C and https://github.com/tip2tail/t2tWinFormAppBarLib , I noticed that .NET 6 applications do not exit properly:

1. The code reaches the bottom of `Program.Main` (i.e., `Application.Run(new Form1());` completes), but the application remains running.
2. If I call `Environment.Exit(0);` at the bottom of `Program.Main`, that call hangs.
3. If the form has no child controls after its constructor runs, the issue does not happen.
4. The issue does not happen in .Net Framework 4.8, but does in .NET 6 (as well as in .NET 7)
5. Adding `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();` to the bottom of `Program.Main` "fixes" the problem.
6. Commenting out `Controls.Add(q)` "fixes" the problem.

Below is sample application.  Note that this is an intentionally simplified, self-contained reproduction.  For example, it doesn't bother to position the window against the dock nor does it handle AppBar messaging.
I was also able to reproduce the problem by directly using both of the libraries mentioned above, but felt that a self-contained example would be easier to follow.

**Warning:** If you run this code, close the window so that  `SHAppBarMessage((UInt32)AppBarMessages.Remove, ref msgData);` has a chance to run. Otherwise, you'll likely lose a chunk of screen real estate until you reboot.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern UInt32 SHAppBarMessage(UInt32 dwMessage, ref APPBARDATA pData);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public Int32 left;
        public Int32 top;
        public Int32 right;
        public Int32 bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct APPBARDATA
    {
        public UInt32 cbSize;
        public IntPtr hWnd;
        public UInt32 uCallbackMessage;
        public UInt32 uEdge;
        public RECT rc;
        public Int32 lParam;
    }

    public enum AppBarMessages
    {
        New = 0x00,
        Remove = 0x01,
        QueryPos = 0x02,
        SetPos = 0x03,
        GetState = 0x04,
        GetTaskBarPos = 0x05,
        Activate = 0x06,
        GetAutoHideBar = 0x07,
        SetAutoHideBar = 0x08,
        WindowPosChanged = 0x09,
        SetState = 0x0a
    }

    Control q;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        APPBARDATA msgData = new APPBARDATA();
        msgData.cbSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(msgData);
        msgData.hWnd = Handle;
        msgData.uCallbackMessage = 0x410; //0x400 WM_User

        SHAppBarMessage((UInt32)AppBarMessages.New, ref msgData);

        msgData = new APPBARDATA();
        msgData.cbSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(msgData);
        msgData.hWnd = Handle;
        msgData.uEdge = (UInt32)1; //ABE_Top
        msgData.rc = new RECT()
        {
            left = 0,
            right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width,
            bottom = 50,
            top = 0
        };


        SHAppBarMessage((UInt32)AppBarMessages.SetPos, ref msgData);

        q = new Button();
        Controls.Add(q);
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        APPBARDATA msgData = new APPBARDATA();
        msgData.cbSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(msgData);
        msgData.hWnd = Handle;
        SHAppBarMessage((UInt32)AppBarMessages.Remove, ref msgData);
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
    }
}
```

#### Why does my application not close gracefully when using an Appbar?

Comment: I tried this NuGet and I got a warning: "package has been restored for framework 4.6 / 4.7 / 4.8" so maybe the package isn't compatable with your project. I am using .NET 7 by the way.

Comment: @Fredy: You're not wrong, though my code example above doesn't use Nuget at all.  The Appbar code is reliant on Pinvoke rather than framework-specific code, so in principle it should still work on .NET 6/7. I'm hoping there's either a fixable bug or an explanation for why the code doesn't work.

Comment: You're right, I didn't dig enough! So, I typed your code and tried about 2 hours of things. What about this: change AppBarMessages.SetPos to AppBarMessages.Activate? Anyway, with this code, I can't see the form get the shape of a bar. But if type the code from codeproject.com (your link), all seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @Fredy: Thank you for trying.  Changing from `SetPos` to `Activate` does prevent `Exit` from hanging.  However, the `SetPos` call is required (`New` creates an app bar and sets which edge it is on and `SetPos` sets its height). For example, if you run my code with Visual Studio maximized on the main monitor, you'll note that Visual Studio shrinks (but stays maximized) to leave room for the app bar.  This restriction is lifted when `Remove` is called. As for the form not being sized/positioned, that's intentional on my part in order to provide a more minimal repro.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Brian. I tried some very strange things, for example, once, adding a TextBox or a docked Panel will work but not a Label or a CheckBox... Now, none works, even with no control in the form. And yes, I could see the VS app shrink!